# Click on item Hide Icon dont refresh screen

Tags: typo3

In Web/List Module when clicking for example on Hide content Element the icon is changing from "actions-edit-hide" to "spinner-circle-dark", but not into "actions-edit-unhide". When Refreshing the page manually the right icon is shown. It seems that the AJAX Call doesn't refresh the list. This happens also by other actions, for example when deleting some Records.

We are Running TYPO3 8.7 LTS with MySQL 5.7.26 und PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

When looking in my Browsers Network Analyse, i see the following call:
https://2019.mbaec.de/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=%2Fajax%2Frecord%2Fprocess&ajaxToken=976157b65a4042508b6b375cf09a50ea17110b90&data[pages][376][hidden]=0

Header:
Host: 2019.mbaec.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: fr,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://2019.mbaec.de/typo3/index.php?M=web_list&moduleToken=73ba2ec59dbfe41e0d9e1b38af45dfdebd5b2b89&id=211&
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: be_lastLoginProvider=1433416747; be_typo_user=5d6f974af357ad400e1380459174c539; Typo3InstallTool=vgehc4q4fs06ph6jn0f7pmg4rd

Result Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 May 2019 13:48:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-JSON: true
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 May 2019 13:48:15 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-JSON
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Contet-Type, X-Forwarded-For, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, PUT, POST
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 64
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Result:
{"redirect":"","messages":[],"hasErrors":true}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed with 8.7.26 (2019-05-09 82429eb0b0 [BUGFIX] Set hasErrors depending on existing errors). Are you sure all your opcode cache  was emptied and that you're really on 8.7.26? 8.7.25 introduced that error as a regression. See https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87971